# Cannot create symbolic link inside different folder

Tags: terminal

I use

```
ln -sF "./Explore" "testExplore"
```

to create a link to folder Explore in the current directory. And it works. If I click on testExplore I see the content of Explore.

However I want to create a link to Explore at "folder/testExplore"

```
    ln -sF "./Explore" "./folder/testExplore"
```

does create the link in the correct folder, but it does not show the contents of the linked folder. what am I missing here?

Comment: Use absolute paths not relative paths.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must use the full path for both the source and target.

`ln -sF /Users/allan/Desktop/Explore /Users/allan/Desktop/folder/testExplore`

Hint:

An easy way to expand out your path (if you are in it already) is to expand the variable `PWD` (use `$PWD` to reference it)

`ln -sF $PWD/Explore $PWD/folder/testExplore`

And if you hit the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key after referencing the PWD variable:

`ln -sF $PWD` <kbd>Tab</kbd>  gives you:

`ln -SF /Users/allan/Desktop/`

Comment: can I use the $PWD in .sh file? or will it only work/translate (to the path) in a terminal window

Comment: `$PWD` can be used in a script, it will be whatever current directory you or your script is in.

Answer (score 3):

You can use relative paths but you need to be in the folder you are creating the link

e.g.

```
cd folder
ln -sF "../Explore" "testExplore"
```

The thing to realise is how is the link expanded. In your case the testExplore has no idea what the path to Explore is it just replaces testExplore by Explore and looks for the file/directory Explore in the directory folder.
In my example the testExplore gets replaced by ../Explore so getting to the original file.

In a symbolic link the original link is replaced by the text that it was linked to and then that full path is used

Comment: strangely enough I also get links to the original folder INSIDE the original folder and recursively so. Any idea as to why?

Comment: See what ls -l shows and then do the text replace yourself

Comment: I dont understand. where should I see was ls-l showws? I have to create a script for OSX (without experience in it), removing stuff manually is not an option. 

The Problem is that the links are not only created at the destination, but for whatever reason also directly inside the source.

Comment: If you don't know what ls -l does you need to read some Unix tutorials before doing anymore - this is a basic level of knowledge which a simple answer can't answer

Comment: huh? I know what ls does.. whatever thank you.

Comment: SO what does ;s -l show - this is really another question

Comment: well it shows the link to itself (among its other content) anyway I created another question for my issue: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/249675/links-are-created-at-source-and-destination